# cookies must be allowed error in microsoft edge?

Tags: windows, browser, microsoft-edge

I have upgraded my pc to windows 10.
But i am getting "cookies must be allowed" error while logging into windows mail or gmail accounts using microsoft edge.
Everything is working fine in other browsers but edge is giving me trouble.
I have already set "don't block cookies " in browsers settings .

Comment: Which build of Windows 10 / Microsoft Edge version are you using?

Comment: I get this on some WordPress installations in Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0. However, being more a software issue (vs. code), this question might get more response in Server Fault?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue when trying to sign in with my Microsoft account on Visual Studio code. I found this link: [Resolve 'cookies must be allowed' error](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-cookies-must-be-allowed-on-windows-10/) and followed all the steps. Step number 3 fixed it for me!

Hope this helps!

EDIT:
From the above link, specifically, I had to do the following steps to ensure it worked:
1. Launch Internet Explorer.
2. Open Tools at the top right corner.
3. Select Internet Options and click **Privacy** tab.
4. Go to Advanced settings and find an option **Don’t block cookies**.
5. After that, open Sites tab and **clear the entire block/allow list of sites**.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)